# python print hanged with text including \x9d

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, printing, decoding

I am trying to convert windows-1252 text to utf8 but python print command is stucked when the text includes this character \x9d. The text is not encoding correctly. I know that. So, I am trying to correct that.

It is the closed double quote in unicode(").

For example: `'...â€œ...centerâ€\x9d'`

`print(x)`

It's surprised that python is stuck when I am trying to print out the text. At first, I thought my function had a infinite loop but it is not.

Comment: sorry @DatTT, i cannot reproduce this behaviour on linux

Comment: sorry @DatTT, I cannot reproduce the problem on windows either.

Comment: >python
Python 3.6.12 (default, Aug 17 2020, 23:45:20) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = '\x9d'
>>> print(x)

@frederic

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 10 Home:** I can reproduce the problem in **[Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/)** (maybe by reason of that `U+009D` is *Operating System Command*?)

All the following output will cause a current tab to hang (however, the Windows Terminal app works…):

- `print('\x9d')` in Python
- `[char]0x9D` in PowerShell 5.1
- `[char]0x9D` in PowerShell 7.1.0

Here's my workaround:

```
mojibake='...â€œ...centerâ€\x9d'
bytearray([ord(c) if ord(c)<256 else ord(c.encode('cp1252')) for c in mojibake]).decode('utf-8')
```

> ```
> '...“...center”'
> ```

Comment: I am getting the same bug on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine